# Подскажите, что выполняет этот массив в коде?

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток! Сразу говорю, я новенький в программировании и вот сижу изучаю разного рода программы для того, чтобы понять как всё это устроено.

Наткнулся на пост с игрой [крестики - нолики на javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/31506/186176), разобрал его от и до, но не могу понять смысл вот этой части кода:

```
function CompTurn() {
  for (i=0; i<9; i++) if (cell[i] == 0) PutHere = i;
  for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
      if (cell[0] == cell[1] && cell[2] == 0 && cell[0] == i) PutHere = 2;
      if (cell[0] == cell[2] && cell[1] == 0 && cell[0] == i) PutHere = 1;
      if (cell[1] == cell[2] && cell[0] == 0 && cell[2] == i) PutHere = 0;
      if (cell[3] == cell[4] && cell[5] == 0 && cell[3] == i) PutHere = 5;
      if (cell[3] == cell[5] && cell[4] == 0 && cell[3] == i) PutHere = 4;
      if (cell[4] == cell[5] && cell[3] == 0 && cell[5] == i) PutHere = 3;
      if (cell[6] == cell[7] && cell[8] == 0 && cell[6] == i) PutHere = 8;
      if (cell[6] == cell[8] && cell[7] == 0 && cell[6] == i) PutHere = 7;
      if (cell[7] == cell[8] && cell[6] == 0 && cell[8] == i) PutHere = 6;

      if (cell[6] == cell[3] && cell[0] == 0 && cell[6] == i) PutHere = 0;
      if (cell[6] == cell[0] && cell[3] == 0 && cell[6] == i) PutHere = 3;
      if (cell[3] == cell[0] && cell[6] == 0 && cell[3] == i) PutHere = 6;
      if (cell[7] == cell[4] && cell[1] == 0 && cell[7] == i) PutHere = 1;
      if (cell[7] == cell[1] && cell[4] == 0 && cell[7] == i) PutHere = 4;
      if (cell[4] == cell[1] && cell[7] == 0 && cell[4] == i) PutHere = 7;
      if (cell[8] == cell[5] && cell[2] == 0 && cell[8] == i) PutHere = 2;
      if (cell[8] == cell[2] && cell[5] == 0 && cell[8] == i) PutHere = 5;
      if (cell[5] == cell[2] && cell[8] == 0 && cell[5] == i) PutHere = 8;

      if (cell[6] == cell[4] && cell[2] == 0 && cell[6] == i) PutHere = 2;
      if (cell[6] == cell[2] && cell[4] == 0 && cell[6] == i) PutHere = 4;
      if (cell[4] == cell[2] && cell[6] == 0 && cell[4] == i) PutHere = 6;
      if (cell[0] == cell[4] && cell[8] == 0 && cell[0] == i) PutHere = 8;
      if (cell[0] == cell[8] && cell[4] == 0 && cell[0] == i) PutHere = 4;
      if (cell[4] == cell[8] && cell[0] == 0 && cell[4] == i) PutHere = 0;
  }
  Zero(PutHere);
  cell[PutHere] = 2;
  if (CheckVictory() == true) {
      alert("Выиграл JavaScript =).");
      GameOver();
  }
}
```

Здесь происходит ход компьютера, но я не могу понять зачем здесь массив с тремя элементами вводится локально. Какую функцию он выполняет? Пробовал убрать, функция работала не правильно, но я так и не понял, в чем её смысл.

Comment: @PloadyFree, после редактирования вопроса, в коде стало не видно о чем спрашивал человек. Там пометка жирным текстом была сделана.

Comment: @Visman там ничего не было выделено жирным текстом, только что пересмотрел. Тем более я не изменил суть вопроса.

Comment: @PloadyFree, в первоначальном варианте у меня эта "for (i=0; i<3; i++) {" строка была жирным текстом на экране :)

Comment: @Visman дело в том, что всё форматирование внутри блока кода убирается. поэтому сейчас там жирный не поставить (все символы экранируются)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Он просто-напросто перебирает все клетки в поле в поиске выигрышного хода и ничего более.
Предполагается, что `PutHere` указывает на индекс клетки, в которую надо сходить.
Само поле выглядит так:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

Если он не находит ни одной выигрышной позиции, просто ходит в первую свободную клетку вот этой строкой кода (т.е. находит её заранее, а потом перезаписывает), если находит выигрышный ход:

```
for (i=0; i<9; i++) if (cell[i] == 0) PutHere = i;
```

Затем идёт обычный перебор, в правильности которого вы можете убедиться на бумаге, используя ту квадратную матрицу, которую я описал чуть выше.

Вот и всё, вся суть алгоритма в это ответе есть.

P.S. И да, и тут массив с 9 элементами, а не с 3, и вводится он не локально (не в этом методе), а глобально, в другой части кода, здесь же он только используется.

Comment: спасибо так понятнее стало)))

Comment: @Waropank Если я вам помог, вы можете поставить + этому ответу и/или сделать его лучшим. Буду благодарен) Иначе - задавайте вопросы, постараюсь ответить.

Answer (score 1):

Это не массив ;) Это цикл. Переменная `i` принимает значение от `0` до `2`.
Судя по коду оригинала, если в клетке `0`, то она пустая, если `1`, то ее занял игрок, если `2`, то компьютер.

То есть сначала при `i = 0` будет выбрана для заполнения клетка в одном ряду с 2мя пустыми.

При втором проходе (`i = 1`) будет выбрана клетка в одном ряду с двумя клетками заполненными игроком (чтобы игрок не выиграл ;) ).

И при третьем проходе (`i = 2`) будет выбрана клетка в одном ряду с двумя клетками заполненными компьютером (тут уже комп выиграл точно).

Comment: вот в чем моя ошибка в понимании))) спасибо)